# how to pass data from one to another function of?

Tags: javascript, css

I get the data. I bring a minimum of information about the user.
When you click on a block, modal window appears. Modal window, more information should be. 
I cannot transfer data in a modal window. Maybe I'm doing wrong. Point out the mistakes, tell me how to correctly, please.
codepen.io/zaytsevav/pen/oBQrOm

Comment: Where is your code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without code it's hard to point out mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store results in a global variable and access it in `myModal` using index.

```
var results = [];
getData('https://api.randomuser.me/1.0/?results=50&nat=gb,us&inc=gender,name,location,email,phone,picture',
  function(data) {

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data["results"].length; i++) {
      var name = data["results"][i]["name"]["title"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["first"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["last"],
        img = data["results"][i]["picture"]["large"];
      html += '<div class="col-md-2 block__user_on" onclick="myModal(this.id)" id="' + [i] + '"> ';
      html += '<img src="' + img + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
      html += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize">' + name + '</p>';
      html += '</div>';
    }
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = html;
    results = data["results"];
  }
);


function myModal(index) {
  var data = results[index];
  console.log(data);
  document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("userModal").innerHTML = '<div>' + data.name.first + " " + data.name.last + ',' + data.location.city + '</div>';

}
```

demo : https://jsbin.com/juxuhixubu/1/edit?js,output

This is will make it work and will help you to understand things. But if the project has more such use cases, you can think about using a modern framework in Javascript, in which this can be done in a much better way.

Comment: Thank you. I will practice my skills, my way is not the best, I know,

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by replacing the myModal function with the code below:

```
function myModal(data) {

    document.getElementById("userModal").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("userModal").appendChild(data);
    document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";

    console.log(data);

}
```

It first erases everything that the modal may have had (by setting its `innerHTML` to nothing) and then it uses the [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method in order to add the div (that is in the `data` string) in the modal window.

You can test that it works [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygQWrN?editors=1111).

**EDIT**

As written on the [documentation for appendChild function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.

That's why the block was removed when you clicked on it.

So, in the code below I used the [cloneNode function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and the problem was solved.

```
function myModal(data) {

    console.log(data);

    document.getElementById("userModal").innerHTML = "";
    dataNode = data.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("userModal").appendChild(dataNode);
    document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";

}
```

Pleasae let me know if that was helpful !

Comment: but the block will be removed from the page

Comment: I need to replace the large picture and add new data, as it can be done here?

Comment: Well then you should pass the data in a different way. I can help you with that. What data do you want to pass to the modal? Only the name and the picture? And what data do you want to add then?

Comment: Well Diode did it. I think that's the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside your cycle:

```
document.getElementById("user").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
document.getElementById(i).setAttribute('data-person', JSON.stringify(data["results"][i]));
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = html;
```

Then add inside your myModal function:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.getAttribute('data-person')));
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null